# Highchart in the loop showing only first chart data

Tags: javascript, jsp, highcharts, jstl

I created a loop where I iterate over two lists of elements in the same time and for each element, I showing appropriate Highchart.

The problem is that for the first list ( model.getFirstList ) all 3 highchart is showing without an issue. But for the second list ( model.getSecondList ), only FIRST Charts is on page, second and third one - is not shwowing any data.

I checked inner html using Dev Console and noticed that the div must handle chart, for charts that are present on the page looks like this:

```html
<div id="ChannelData" class="a-section a-spacing-none va-metrics-main-graph" data-highcharts-chart="5">
```

BUT for charts that are not shows on the page IS like this:

```html
<div id="ChannelData" class="a-section a-spacing-none va-metrics-main-graph">
```

So it does not have attribute  **data-highcharts-chart**,as well as inner div that has all attributes to build the chart. While javascript with all data I need for missing charts in also presented.

**This is my code, where I iterate over two lists in one loop and showing correspondent to the list items , charts**

```html
<c:forEach items="${model.getFirstList}" varStatus="loop" > 
<a:gridColumn gridUnits="3">
<mt:TimeSeriesDataGraphtimeSeriesData="${model.{model.getFirstList[loop.index]}" />
<input type="button" value="Channels Metrics" onclick="getChannelsData('${loop.index}')"/>
</a:gridColumn>                                
<a:gridColumn gridUnits="3">
<mt:TimeSeriesDataGraph timeSeriesData="${model.getSecondList[loop.index]}" />
<input type="button" value="All Metrics" onclick="getAllData('${loop.index}')"/>
</a:gridColumn> 
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has occurred, because all html elements I decided to renderTo() my chart had the same id. Giving them different ids fixed the problem.